# How to get the class reference name in Java using reflection

Tags: java, json, reflection

I have a json  like

> "Someform":"Somebuilder"

.I have parsed the json and retrieved value for Someform as below.

> String formBuilder = pageJson.getString("Someform");

Now formBuilder contains "**Someform**" reference .

How do I get the class name for this i.e Someformclass  .
I used reflection like below

> String className = formBuilder.getClass().getSimpleName();

Above statement is giving me **String class** name not the someform class name  since formBuilder is String class.
How do I get the someform class name which is dynamic so that I can pass this as argument to

> Class builderName = Class.forName(className);

and invoke the method in that class.To be more precise I need to get the class name for Someform like SomeForm.class instead of String class.

Any help would be appreciated .
TIA.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be `Class.forName(formBuilder)`, or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: Here  `"Someform":"Somebuilder"`, `Somebuilder` doesn't look like as a qualified class name :

Comment: yes David you are right I am not specifying fully qualified name.Is there any way to decide the package name at runtime which will solve my problem I hope

Comment: I have used reflection for several years and I don't think you can load a class without the fully qualified class name. In any case, I never had to deal with this problem. Why you can't get the qualified class name?

Comment: If that is the only case I would prefer to go with fully qualified name  then .Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Where should the missing package name come from? Magic?

Answer (score 0):

If formBuilder is the name of the class you want, you can do:

```
Class builderName = Class.forName(formBuilder);
```

Comment: hey I already tried this Class.forName(formBuilder);Class.forName will take fully qualified name If I use this it will throw ClassCastException

Comment: Same here, also getting the same exception